# Adding debugging breaks during optimization in R

Tags: r, debugging, optimization, break

Say I have the following function to optimize:

```
func <- function(x) {
  mx <- matrix(x, nrow = 2)
  inv <- solve(mx)
  det(inv)
}
```

Minimizing this function is not a problem, as long as `x` is always invertible (e.g., running `optim(c(1, 0, 0, 1), func)` yields no errors).

Now let's feed it an unsolvable matrix right from the start. Running `optim(c(0, 0, 0, 0), func)` yields

> Error in solve.default(mx) : 
>     Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0

Now imagine the source of the problem is not so obvious, so I add the if-statement below to try to investigate why the matrix is not invertible.

```
func <- function(x) {
  mx <- matrix(x, nrow = 2)
  if (class(try(solve(mx))) == "try-error") {
    break
  }
  inv <- solve(mx)
  det(inv)
}
```

The `break` statement above is **intended to have R enter debugging mode on that line**, but it doesn't do that. The documentation says that `break` "breaks out of a for, while or repeat loop", so an `optim()` run is implicitly excluded. What I am supposed to write to get the desired result?

Comment: have you tried the `browser()` function? This typically works for entering a debugging environment from within a function call.

Comment: @ruaridhw, thanks for the input. I wasn't aware of that function. Replacing it for break definitely works!

Comment: No worries! I'll add it as an answer so that you can close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`browser()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/browser.html) function is ideal for debugging in RStudio. The other option is to add breakpoints within RStudio however this obviously relies on the IDE and is not actually part of your code.

```
if (class(try(solve(mx))) == "try-error") {
  browser()
}
```

Once the code reaches `browser()` an interactive session with the current environment as at the `browser` call is invoked which also allows you to run commands in the console. This helps a lot for trialling code that will live within a function and you're not necessarily sure how it will play out once the code arrives at that line.

For a comparison of these methods in addition to information on how to interpret the callstack see [this article](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio).